# Hyper parameters to tune in Bayesian network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, hyperparameter, tuning

In tree based models and neural networks, we can optimised the models by tuning the hyper parameters(such as: learning rate, number of neutrons.. etc). Is there a hyper parameters to tune in Bayesian networks?

Thank you,
Shosho